# What is first Chern class and how to calculate it?

Tags: differential-geometry

Apparently [Calabi-Yau manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold) have vanishing first Chern class. Is there some simple explanation for what first Chern class of a manifold means? How to calculate it for a given metric (in physicist notation)?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 0):

There are plent of books and review articles about Chern classes for physicists, but it would help to know more about what you already know before I can make recommendations. The fact that you mention  an advanced topic like Calabi-Yau manifolds while not knowing  about much simpler stuff like Chern classes makes me wonder what it is you are studying, and at what stage you are at. Can you give a hint? -- then I can give much better advice.

One thing is useful to know that is that Chern classes characterise line bundles, and for most types of manifolds a line bundle(a U(1) gauge field)  is something extra. Calabi-Yau manifolds, however, are Kahler manifolds and they have a built-in line bundle. Do you know what a Kahler manifold is?

Comment: I have studied differential geometry only for as much as was taught during a general relativity course. I'm only interested in manifolds with (pseudo-)Riemannian structure.

Comment: I don't know what a Kahler manifold is.

Comment: If that built-in line bundle is the (anti-)canonical line bundle, then *all* smooth manifolds have that built-in.

Comment: @Bence Racsko. I did not know that. How does it work, and does it have a Chern class?

Comment: The canonical bundle is just the exterior bundle $\bigwedge^n M$, which always exists. I don't know much about characteristic classes however, so I cannot anwer that.